# Can't align text to unordered list custom bullet when it included an anchor

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to create a unordered list with a defined bullet color that aligns like a traditional bulleted list when an anchor is included. 
I've create an unordered list with the correct alignment using the following code:

```css
ul li.purchase::before {
  list-style: none;
  content: "\2022";
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="purchase">Originals</li>
  <li class="purchase">Prints</li>
  <li class="purchase">Apparel</li>
  <li class="purchase">Other Merchandize</li>
</ul>
```

That code works perfectly, but when I add an anchor to the HTML code:

```css
ul li.purchase::before {
  list-style: none;
  content: "\2022";
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="purchase"><a href="#">Originals</a></li>
  <li class="purchase"><a href="#">Prints</a></li>
  <li class="purchase"><a href="#">Apparel</a></li>
  <li class="purchase"><a href="#">Other Merchandize</a></li>
</ul>
```

The text shifts down and is no longer aligned with the bullet.  I assume the problem lies with the anchor creating a block but I was unable to address the problem by adding a class selector to the anchor and changing the display to inline-block.  I'm still learning to code and hope you can help me with a solution.

Comment: Anchor tags (`<a>`) are inline by default, so the only thing I can think of is that you have a reset affecting the display of your anchor tags. A question I have is what browser are you testing this in ? I tried it in Codepen and it seems to work fine with no other styles: https://codepen.io/codingmatty/pen/LqOQJg

Comment: add you full html / css into the question please, the given code do not reproduce the problem

Comment: i have created a code snippet of of your code.  please tell us what is wrong in those 2 snippets. thanks

Answer (score -1):

This issue can be solved easily by giving the "vertical-align" property to the anchor tag in your li. Vertical align has multiple values. You can try in the inpector of your browser whichever value works for you. Eg: " vertical-align: middle; ".